# i want to find and hightlight a specific word in a excel, but the whole cell is getting highlighted pls help me

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Sample()
Dim fnd As String
Dim MyAr
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range, FoundCell As Range, LastCell As Range, myRange As Range

Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)

fnd = "university/checklist"

MyAr = Split(fnd, "/")

    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)

        Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=MyAr(i), after:=LastCell)

        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
        End If
Set rng = FoundCell
            Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
                Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
                    Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)
                If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
            Loop
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 3
End If

    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: If you want coloring only specific characters, you cannot use a `Union` range. You should color it for each found cell.

Answer (score 1):

First of, try to tidy a bit your code example, it's quite messy hence I am not sure of what you are actually trying to achieve. Some accompanying comments would help also

Anyway, one thing is for sure :

```
rng.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

will attribute a color to the whole text in the selected range. To specify only a subset of the text in the range, you need to use :

```
rng.Characters(Start:=x, Length:=y).Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

Where x being the starting character and Length being the length that you want to turn into the given font color.

You can find the start value and length using

```
start = InStr(1, rng, MyAr(i))
length = len(MyAr(i))
```

Which will lead to the following line

```
rng.Characters(Start:=start, Length:=length).Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

And as specified by FaneDuru, it should be done on a cell by cell basis. Either you do it instead of the Union, or you look on the cells within the rng.

```
for cell in rng.Cells
    start = InStr(1, cell, MyAr(i))
    ...
next cell
```

Moreover, as described here, it will only color the first occurrence.

If the value you are looking for can appear several time, you either need an alternate way or set some iteration until there are no more matches by modifying the starting position in the `InStr` where 1 would become the last matched position + 1

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next updated code. As I said in my above comment you cannot use a `Union` range for what you try doing, because you need to search for each cell and find the appropriate cell characters to be colored. You can iterate between such a range again but nothing will be gain:

```
Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String, MyAr, i As Long, pos As Long
Dim FoundCell As Range, LastCell As Range, myRange As Range

Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set LastCell = myRange.cells(myRange.cells.count)

fnd = "university/checklist"

MyAr = Split(fnd, "/")

    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)

        Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(MyAr(i)), , , xlPart

        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
            pos = InStr(1, FoundCell.Value, MyAr(i), vbTextCompare)
            FoundCell.Characters(pos, Len(MyAr(i))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
            
            Do
                Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(FoundCell)
                 pos = InStr(1, FoundCell.Value, MyAr(i))
                 FoundCell.Characters(pos, Len(MyAr(i))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
            Loop While FoundCell.Address <> FirstFound
       End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

If the range to be processed is large, you should use some optimization lines as `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, `Application.EnableEvents = False` and
`Application.Calculation = xlManual` at the beginning of the code and ending with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, `Application.EnableEvents = False` and
`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

Answer (score 1):

### Highlight Strings in Cells

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightStrings()
    
    Const CriteriaList As String = "university,checklist"
    Const CriteriaColor As Long = vbRed

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange

    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    
    Dim c As Long
    Dim cLen As Long
    Dim cString As String
    
    Dim fCell As Range
    Dim fArr() As String
    Dim f As Long
    Dim fPos As Long
    Dim fString As String
    Dim fFirstAddress As String
    
    For c = 0 To UBound(Criteria)
        cString = Criteria(c)
        cLen = Len(cString)
        Set fCell = rg.Find(cString, , xlFormulas, xlPart)
        If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
            fFirstAddress = fCell.Address
            Do
                fString = fCell.Value
                fPos = 1
                fArr = Split(fString, cString, , vbTextCompare)
                For f = 0 To UBound(fArr) - 1
                    fPos = fPos + Len(fArr(f))
                    fCell.Characters(fPos, cLen).Font.Color = CriteriaColor
                    fPos = fPos + cLen
                Next f
                Set fCell = rg.FindNext(fCell)
            Loop Until fCell.Address = fFirstAddress
        End If
    Next c
    
    MsgBox "Criteria strings highlighted.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Please could you add as a function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Let's call this function of yours `Highlight`. How exactly would you use this function? Give us an example.